# Jquery keypress event, event.keycode or event.which is always 0 in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, unicode-literals

I am developing a transliterate application in which when an user typing, the character should be replaced with unicode character. For that I am getting the keycode value on kepress event and based on that I am setting unicode character. It is working fine in desktop. But, not works in android. I have searched regarding this. None of the solution worked. Either it returns 0 or 229. Someone please help me.

The code

```
$("input").on('input keypress propertychange', function(e){
            if (!isIE){
        Key = e.which;
    }
    else {
        Key = e.keyCode; 
    }

    Char = String.fromCharCode(Key);
...
           });
```

The value of Key if getting correct results in desktop browsers. But, always 0 in android browsers.

Look at my my app desktop as well as android- https://search.tamilpriyan.com (when you type in the input field, it changes to Tamil character. But, not woking in android)